# Building a Search Engine.

Tags: java, web

I am trying to build a website. User able input certain data from the search field which returns relevant information from the database. What approach should I take to do this project? I am new in programming. I just need suggestions and steps. Thank you. Preferred P.L is Java and MySQL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kudos to you for getting started with programming. However, Stack Overflow is a place to ask specific questions about a specific problem you have encountered and are not able to solve on your own. This is not the right place to ask broad questions whose answers are subjective. It would be great if you could try this on your own first, then let us know if you have a specific problem or question we can help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, there are some already mature options out there. such as:

1. Lucene: https://lucene.apache.org/
2. Solr: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/
3. Elastic search: https://www.elastic.co/

I strongly encourage you to take a look to them and see which one suits your project best.